# Search for website pages in Bootstrap

Tags: search, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a beginner, trying to teach myself code. I know HTML and have recently learnt the basics of Javascript syntax and bootstrap - I realise the best way to learn is to build something. So I am trying to build a website where users can search for famous people to see what books they recommend. For example, if I want to know what books Elon Musk would recommend, I should be able to type in his name and it would take me to a page where there is a list of all books recommended by him.

I have the index page ready looking something like google, and I am trying to understand how I can have the search bar functioning so people can search through all the pages I would build. I realise I need the auto complete feature to work so people can type in the first few letters of the person's name and click on the suggestion to go to the page.

Here's my code so far:

```css
 #content {height: 100%;}
 html, body {height: 100%;}

 .center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- Bootstrap JS from CDN -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS from CDN -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>

 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span4"></div>
      <div class="span4"><img class="center-block" src="images/logo.png" width="270" height="95" alt="Google" id="logo"></div>
      <div class="span4"></div>
    </div>

<div class="row">    
 <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
  <div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Search term...">
       <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
    </span>
  </div>
 </div>         
</div>
</div>
</div> 

<div id="footer">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a href="#">Submit</a></li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

as you said, best way to learn is building something on your own from scratch. To create the functionality you described you need:

- **server** for responding to the requests made by browser. I suggest starting with **Node js** especially with **express** (https://expressjs.com/). It's really simple to install and get started.
- **database (or just static json file)** with node you can use for example **Mongo db** with **Mongoose** (http://mongoosejs.com/)
- **front-end framework and libraries** you are using bootstrap which is fine! Add **React js** (https://facebook.github.io/react/) to that and you are ready to go!

So my suggestion is to use those libraries/frameworks and learn just bit by bit. Start from server and try creating some basic pages (or just page). You can fetch the autocomplete data then with **AJAX** techinque. React has lot of well written components and for example for ajax autocomplete you can use this: https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/

Happy learning!

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting closer now!!